# Python - out of bounds error in nested loop

Tags: python

Can any one please help me to understand why i always get an error
regarding "index out of bounds"?

the issue is to get a sting and remove the vowels and get the new string back without the vowels

**code:**

```
def disemvowel(string):
    vowel=['E','A','I','O','U','Y','e','a','i','o','u','y']
    string = list(string)
    lenString = len(string)
    print (lenString)
    for i in range(0, lenString):
        for j in range(0, 12):
            if (string[i] == vowel[j]):
                print ("matched")
                del string[i]
    string = ''.join(string)
    print (string)
    return string
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the function and also the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Is `string` a `list` object or a `str` abject?

Comment: you `del string[i]` so string is not enough `length`; BTW, better not use `string` as a variable name.

Comment: Use a set for `vowel`, not a list. Lookup is O(1) for a set, O(n) for a list. Then you don't need the `for j ...` loop

Comment: Learn about **list comprehensions**. Never manually delete items from a string if <condition> is false; use a list comprehension `[ch if cond(ch) for ch in word]`. No need to declare an index to iterate over vowel `for j in range(0, len(vowel))`

Answer (score 2):

More pythonic, use `set` instead as @smci suggested:

```
def disemvowel(s):
    vowel = {'E', 'A', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y', 'e', 'a', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}
    return ''.join((char for char in s if char not in vowel))
```

Comment: Use a set for `vowel`, not a list. Lookup is O(1) for a set, O(n) for a list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting construct a new string

```
def disemvowel(string):
    vowel=['E','A','I','O','U','Y','e','a','i','o','u','y']
    string = list(string)
    final_string = []
    lenString = len(string)
    print (lenString)
    for i in range(0, lenString):
        for j in range(0, 12):
            if (string[i] == vowel[j]):
                print ("matched")
                final_string += string[i]
    string = ''.join(final_string)
    print (final_string)
    return final_string
```

Comment: Hi, you constructing the vowels that i don't need them. i get a string of vowels instead of string without the vowels.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the translate function in the string library:

```
import string

def disemvowel(s):
    return string.translate(s, string.maketrans("",""), "EAIOUYeaiouy")

print disemvowel("Hello World")
```

> Hll Wrld